# how to use multiple ng-click with one single boolean? AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs

pretty new to angularJS so this question might be dumb!
I have 7 `<span>` including in it the 7 days of the week.
The idea is that each time the user clicks on one days, thanks to a ng-show a table with some data for that day will appear.

I have an issue with the "buttons" (for buttons I mean the  with the clickable text inside) , I use ng-click and ng-class so when you click on a day, the text will get bigger and colored, so you know what day you selected!

```
ng-class="{'activeSelection': isActive}" ng-click="isActive = !isActive"


.activeSelection {
transform: scale(1.2);
color: #fff;
```

}

so if there was only one day, this would work great, but what happens is when I click on a day, ALL of the other days get applied the "activeSelection" class.

I understand that this happens because the BOOL isActive it's the same for every day, so when I click on a day and it gets "true", all days get the same so all days get big and colored!

How can I solve this? Initially I thought to make for each day a different BOOL like this:

```
isActive, isActive2, isActive3, isActive4..
```

but there are some problems, first, when I click on another day after I clicked on one already, I want the previous day to lose the class, so only one day is big at a time! So if new day is clicked, the previous day returns small size like the others!

For the tables, I'll use a ng-show with a bool that we get when a day is clicked, so if monday is clicked, the monday table will show, but if we click wednesday, the monday table disappears, and the wednesday one appears.

What's the best approach to this? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one thing on click of each day, pass some param to function and update $scope. try below example

```
<button ng-click="changeDay(1)"> Day 1</button>
<button ng-click="changeDay(2)"> Day 2</button>
<button ng-click="changeDay(3)"> Day 3</button>

<div ng-class="{'activeSelection': day==1}">1 Selection</div>
<div ng-class="{'activeSelection': day==2}">2 Selection</div>
<div ng-class="{'activeSelection': day==3}">3 Selection</div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.day =0;
$scope.changeDay = (day)=>{
    $scope.day =day;
}
```

Comment: with `ng-repeat` it would be simpler: `<div ng-repeat="day in week"><button ng-click="changeDay($index)">Day {{$index + 1}}</button></div>` (same for _selections_)

Comment: this works @Rahul , thank you, for the ng-repeat option in the comments, the problem with that would be this, I take the dates of the days from a database like this, getting the first day of the week first: `{{vm.date | amDateFormat : 'dddd'}} {{vm.date | amDateFormat : 'DD.MM.'}}` and for each consecutive day `{{vm.date | amAdd : '1' : 'day' | amDateFormat : 'dddd'}} {{vm.date | amAdd : '1' : 'day' | amDateFormat : 'DD.MM.'}}`  so using a ng-repeat as far as I know would be hard and overkill! thank you